# Flag for ContentEditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Strange... there are quite a lot of qustion about this `attr` here on StackOverflow, but none answered my folowing question:

I have a `span` (only for example), in which have enabled `ContentEditable`. I only want to save the changed elements (via jQuery and ajax).

*The problem:*

How can I assure whether an element has changed?

`newVAl==oldVal` is not an option: I dont want to save old value to compare.

Is there any flag (or some other indicator) which states: "`isChanged`" ?

Comment: "I dont want to save old value to compare"... well I think you're going to have to. Why can you not do that?

Comment: @JamesAllardice the same reason a row in datatable in c# has a state - modified or deleted flags

Comment: That is not a reason why you wouldn't want to save the data of the `span`

Comment: No, there is no such flag. The only thing what you could do is raise one on the `keyup` event, but that doesn't guarantee that a subsequent edit will not undo any changes made. The reason you mention is not a reason just a reiteration of what you wish for.

Comment: @d_inevitable do you really believe i should save long text ( in many areas of the page) - just to equate it to the new text ? its very bad approach.... ( in programming anyway)

Comment: If the browser would be maintaining such a flag it would need to do just the same thing. Or use some hash functions instead. There are md5 and sha1 libs for js. But is it really worth loading these libs for just a little bit more RAM? After all the memory you would use would never exceed the double of the html document.

Comment: Think about text inputs and textareas: do they have such a flag to know if they have been modified?: No. So don't expect such flag for contentEditable any time soon. You have to check the current value with the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use html5 data attributes like the following:

```
$('element').change(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-edited', true);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tBbnT/2/)**

Comment: It is easy to get a false positive with this one, when the user edits the field and then undoes all his changes. However if you don't want to compare against the original string then this is only way to go, because hash functions are not available in the JS Core. In most cases this false positive shouldn't make much of a problem. When you edit any document and then undo you changes the editor usually will also mark it as "unsaved". So this is standard practice. +1

Comment: @d_inevitable Of course you have to do some work in this code, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann is there anything special with  specific `data-edited` name you chosen  ? I sometime see this `data-XXX` in html(5) element. but was there any special reason you chosen this specific name ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, you can chose any name you want after `data-`.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann but is the `data-` prefix is mandatory ? how can I later use these attributes ? only by `xx.dataset`?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann but it aint gonna collide with jqeury.data('a',1) ? I mean Jq build it for their dom data and now html uses it for their goals...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[contenteditable]').focus(function(){
      $(this).attr("data-old",$(this).html());
}).blur(function(){
   if( $(this).html() != $(this).attr("data-old") ){
       changed, save ... 
   }
});
```

Update:

### [Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLVZ8/)